# How to create an Azure AppendBlob from node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-storage

I have installed the npm **azure-storage** package.

On Azure I have created a Storage Account and a container.

I then try to create an Append Blob:

```js
const azure = require('azure-storage');
const service = azure.createBlobService("[ACCOUNT]", "[KEY]");
service.createAppendBlobFromText("[CONTAINER]",
                                 "some-blob-name", 
                                 "some-text", 
                                 {},
                                (err, result) => {
   console.log('err ->',err);
   console.log('result ->',result);
});
```

The result of calling this is:

```
err -> { Error
    at Function.StorageServiceClient._normalizeError (/[REMOVED]/node_modules/azure-storage/lib/common/services/storageserviceclient.js:1191:23)
    at BlobService.StorageServiceClient._processResponse (/[REMOVED]/node_modules/azure-storage/lib/common/services/storageserviceclient.js:738:50)
    at Request.processResponseCallback [as _callback] (/[REMOVED]/node_modules/azure-storage/lib/common/services/storageserviceclient.js:311:37)
    at Request.self.callback (/[REMOVED]/node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:125:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:213:7)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/[REMOVED]/node_modules/request/request.js:1163:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/[REMOVED]/node_modules/request/request.js:1085:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:314:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:110:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:207:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1045:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
  name: 'StorageError',
  message: 'Append blobs are not supported.\nRequestId:ed1777f4-601c-00cf-19a0-bb77ba000000\nTime:2018-03-14T14:25:50.8138962Z',
  code: 'BlobTypeNotSupported',
  statusCode: 400,
  requestId: 'ed1777f4-601c-00cf-19a0-bb77ba000000' }
result -> null
```

I have not been able to find anything, when searching for the error.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the redundancy kind of the storage account in which you're trying to create this blob.

Blob type support varies by the storage account redundancy kind.

For example, `ZRS Classic` redundancy kind of storage account only supports `Block Blob` while `Premium LRS` redundancy kind of storage account only supports `Page Blob`.

Comment: Part of the documentation suggested this, but it was not very clear. Block Blobs was listed when looking at the container properties, which made me think it was supported. Anyways when creating a ZRS classic the code works. So thank you.